# What is the behavior of scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

The documentation for `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` on the [ExecutionContext](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.scala) trait reads:

> It is possible to simply import
>   `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` to obtain an
>   implicit `ExecutionContext`. This global context is a reasonable
>   default thread pool

What does it mean by "reasonable default"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Default**

It's a fixed size [**ThreadPool**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-), which has as many threads as the processors on the machine. A reasonable default means it's good for most things most of the time.

**What a "good" thread pool is**

First, it's important to understand you only have as many threads as the cores on the machine. All other threads are so called demon threads and it's all about being smart with queue-ing and executing.(at language/library level).

**CachedThreadPool: Many short lived/cheap tasks**

The type of thread pools you spawn vastly depend on the actions they are mean to perform. For a lot of short lived actions(say database queries), you would go a with a cached thread pool.

Because each individual task is relatively cheap but spawning a new thread is expensive, you are better off with a [**CachedThreadPool**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool-int-).

**FixedThreadPool: Long running/expensive tasks**

In contrast with the above, for very expensive operations, you probably want to limit the amount of threads running at one time, for various reasons: memory, performance etc.

**ForkJoinPool: Divide et impera**

This type of pool is useful when you need to perform a very large computation, but you can divide it into smaller bits individual workers can compute.

The list goes on and on. Bottom line, Scala gives you something in between all of the above. Specifically, Scala tries to create a ForkJoinPool and defaults to a ThreadPoolExecutor if the first fails.

```
try {
  new ForkJoinPool(
    desiredParallelism,
    threadFactory,
    uncaughtExceptionHandler,
    true) // Async all the way baby
} catch {
  case NonFatal(t) =>
    System.err.println("Failed to create ForkJoinPool for the default ExecutionContext, falling back to ThreadPoolExecutor")
    t.printStackTrace(System.err)
    val exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
      desiredParallelism,
      desiredParallelism,
      5L,
      TimeUnit.MINUTES,
      new LinkedBlockingQueue[Runnable],
      threadFactory
    )
    exec.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)
    exec
}
```

}

The **[full](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-)** list here.

Comment: @som-snytt No problem, I will challenge you during normal work hours. On this occasion the oversight was mine, thank you for spotting it.

Comment: thanks. I had to get up at 8 a.m. anyway to walk the kid to school. 4 a.m. is always a fuzzy time.

Comment: Is there a way to get a ThreadPoolExecutor from the current context?

Comment: On the [scala-lang docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#the-global-execution-context) it is stated, that the default is a ForkJoinPool. Am I missing something, or has it changed since this answer?

Comment: @CasperThuleHansen I think the end of my answer says the same thing, as copy pasted from the Scala source tree at the time of the answer. Arguably it's been 1.5 years so things may have well changed.

Comment: Ah yes, I just got confused by the title Default